# Group Alias in Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

In Linux, especially Ubuntu and Arch, is there a way to add an alias to a group name? Specifically, I have a python script which checks for the group 'nogroup', which is called 'nobody' on Arch. I'd like to not change the script, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupadd` has an option `--non-unique` (short version `-o`), which when combined with `--gid` (short version `-g`) allows creating groups with a non-unique group ID. Two groups with the same group ID can be used interchangeably (according to the testing I've done on my machine).

Some examples:

```bsh
groupadd --non-unique --gid <existing group ID> <new alias>

groupadd --non-unique --gid $(getent group nobody | awk -F : -e '{print $3}') nogroup
```